# show certain column for user type

Tags: reactjs, react-table

After login I store user type in the local storage. There are types of users who should see last column of react table. I'm having problem in implementing this.

```
<ReactTable
          data={data}
          filterable
          defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) =>
            String(row[filter.id]) === filter.value}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: "Name",
              id: "name",
              accessor: "item.name",
              filterMethod: (filter, rows) =>
                matchSorter(rows, filter.value, { keys: ["name"] }),
              filterAll: true
            },
            {
              Header: "Public/Rare",
              id: "public_or_rare",
              accessor: "item.public_or_rare",
              filterMethod: (filter, rows) =>
                matchSorter(rows, filter.value, { keys: ["public_or_rare"] }),
              filterAll: true
            },
            {
              //I want to show something here if user is local or foreigner
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
```

In top of page I retrieved user type as below,
`let user_type = localStorage.getItem('user_type');`

How can I render last column if user is those type user ?

Answer (score 0):

Columns are defined in a table. You have this definition `inlined` - defined in place of usage.

You can always define this array earlier and use (pass as property) a reference to the array object.

Define columns content/config conditionally. In this case (the last column) you can define base config and conditionally extend it (array push) with additional column definition.

All these definitions can be done in `render` method, before JSX part ( `return (` ) using normal/valnilla javascript.